# How can I edit data the copy/paste buffer in terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, console

I'd like to edit data copy/paste buffer. For example i have in buffer ABC, how can I edit ABC to 123 in terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing shift and the arrow keys will select text.
Crtl + Alt + C will copy that text to clipboard/buffer
Ctrl + Alt + X will cut that text to clipboard/buffer
Crtl + Alt + V will paste the clipboard/buffer at the current cursor location

Editing data in the buffer can be done like:
Paste the text anywhere, edit it, select it and cut it to clipboard/buffer.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I need do it on terminal, using alias

Comment: So paste to terminal, edit, select, copy.

Comment: These shortcuts are for using the clipboard/buffer in Terminal.